# sizeof operator fails on bitwise & in C

Tags: c, sizeof, bitwise-and

Thanks for your response, the %zu specifiers work okay with the sizeof operator, size gets printed okay and x and y values also. 
But when I changed all of those specifiers to %lld, which should print actual x and y values(as they are long long), it prints some random garbage values.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      long long x=500000000007;
      long long y=1;
      printf("size of x : %lld,x = %lld, size of y : %lld, y : %lld\n",sizeof(x),x,sizeof(y),y); 

      if(x & y)
      {
        printf("ODD IT IS :), x&1 = %lld, size of x&1 = %lld\n",x&y,sizeof(x&y) );//<--- this line
      }



      printf("After If statement ---> size of x : %lld,x = %lld\n",sizeof(x),x); 

      return 0;
    }

    Output on linux 32 bit system(Ubuntu) using gcc compiler
      size of x : 7661335479756783624,x = 34359738484, size of y : 1, y : -4160453359
      ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 34359738376
      After If statement ---> size of x : 7661335479756783624,x = 34359738484
```

Now, the question is - Why are the values in variables x and y affected by the use of specifier for the sizeof operator
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size do you expect?

Comment: `sizeof` takes a type or a variable (in which case, the variable is replaced with its type **during compilation**). It does not take expressions (such as `x&y` for example).

Comment: @barakmanos: Untrue. It takes a type or an expression. The expression is not evaluated unless it is a VLA.

Comment: @rici: Since when is a VLA considered an expression?

Comment: @barakmanos: When it's not the operand of either `&` or `sizeof`.

Comment: @barakmanos-http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: You don't state what size you do get, but your comment suggests that you don't get 8.  What size do you get, and which compiler are you using (on which platform)?

Comment: None of those `printf` statements has a correct format specifier for the `sizeof` argument. It should be `%zu`. `%ld` is too short; `%lld` is too long; and both are signed.

Comment: Post the actual output you are getting, and ask a question.

Comment: @barakmanos By "VLA" he means *expression of variably modified type*.

Comment: @barakmanos `sizeof` certainly does take expressions, have you never seen usages such as `sizeof 1`, or `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` ?  The grammar specification is: **sizeof** *unary-expression*  , or **sizeof  (** *type-name* **)**

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Seen - yes, used - not really. Thank you for the info :)

Comment: @rici %z is correct for C99, but good luck having Microsoft support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Theory

The problem is that you're not using the correct format specification to print `sizeof()`.

```
printf("size of x : %d,x = %lld, size of y : %d, y : %lld\n", sizeof(x), x, sizeof(y), y);
```

You're using `%d`, which expects an `int`, to print a `size_t` which is (a) an unsigned type and (b) most probably 8 bytes, not 4 bytes like an `int` would be.  The correct way to print `size_t` (like the result of `sizeof`) is with the `z` modifier:

```
printf("size of x: %zu, x = %lld, size of y: %zu, y = %lld\n", sizeof(x), x, sizeof(y), y);
```

If you don't have support for `%zu` in the library, then cast the result of `sizeof(x)` etc to `int` explicitly.  However, if you have support for `long long`, it is unlikely that the library does not support `%zu`.

If you use GCC, it should have been warning you about type mismatches in the argument list to `printf()`.

When you use the wrong type, the wrong values get picked off the stack inside `printf()`.  You push 4 units of 8 bytes on the stack, but tell `printf()` to read 4 bytes, 8 bytes, 4 bytes and 8 bytes.

---

#### Compiling and fixing the code

Taking your original code, `sz1.c`, with minor modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long x=500000000007;
    long long y=1;

    printf("size of x : %d, x = %lld, size of y : %d, y : %lld\n", sizeof(x), x, sizeof(y), y); 
    printf("ODD IT IS :), x&1 = %d, size of x&1 = %lld\n", x&y, sizeof(x&y));
    printf("After If statement ---> size of x : %d, x = %lld\n", sizeof(x), x); 

    return 0;
}
```

Then compiling it gives me lots of warnings (this is GCC 4.8.1, and for some reason, it produces two copies of each warning for format warnings — it is bad, but not quite that bad!):

```
$ gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     sz1.c -o sz1
sz1.c: In function ‘main’:
sz1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("size of x : %d, x = %lld, size of y : %d, y : %lld\n", sizeof(x), x, sizeof(y), y); 
     ^
sz1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("ODD IT IS :), x&1 = %d, size of x&1 = %lld\n", x&y, sizeof(x&y));
     ^
sz1.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
sz1.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("After If statement ---> size of x : %d, x = %lld\n", sizeof(x), x); 
     ^
sz1.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
$
```

This version, `sz2.c`, has the correct type specifiers (so it compiles without any warnings):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long x=500000000007;
    long long y=1;
    printf("size of x : %zu, x = %lld, size of y : %zu, y : %lld\n", sizeof(x), x, sizeof(y), y); 
    printf("ODD IT IS :), x&1 = %lld, size of x&1 = %zu\n", x&y, sizeof(x&y) );//<--- this line
    printf("After If statement ---> size of x : %zu, x = %lld\n", sizeof(x), x); 
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, on Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GCC 4.8.1, the output of the two programs is basically the same:

```
$ ./sz1 
size of x : 8, x = 500000000007, size of y : 8, y : 1
ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 8
After If statement ---> size of x : 8, x = 500000000007
$ ./sz2
size of x : 8, x = 500000000007, size of y : 8, y : 1
ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 8
After If statement ---> size of x : 8, x = 500000000007
$
```

However, compile the same code as 32-bit instead of 64-bit executable, and then there are differences:

```
$  ./sz1 
size of x : 8, x = 500000000007, size of y : 8, y : 1
ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 34359738368
After If statement ---> size of x : 8, x = 500000000007
$ ./sz2
size of x : 8, x = 500000000007, size of y : 8, y : 1
ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 8
After If statement ---> size of x : 8, x = 500000000007
$
```

#### Why?

> Why does it give size as large as 34359738368 if I print it using `%lld`?

Because of the way the data is stacked.  Assuming that you have a 32-bit compilation, the 'ODD' call to `printf()` pushes:

1. The pointer to the format.
2. 8 bytes for the value of `x&y` (because both `x` and `y` are `long long`, so `x&y` is also a `long long`).
3. 4 bytes for the value of `sizeof(x&y)` (assuming a 32-bit compilation, with `sizeof(size_t) == 4`.

The incorrect format tells `printf()` that:

1. It should use 4 bytes off the stack to print the first value (`%d`) — `x&y` — instead of the correct 8 bytes.
2. It should use 8 bytes off the stack to print the second value (`%lld`) — `sizeof(x&y)` — instead of the correct 4 bytes.

Because the machine is little-endian (presumably an Intel machine), the first 4 bytes are the same whether the value is 4 bytes or 8 bytes, but the misinterpretation of the rest occurs because the 4 bytes of zeros from the end of the `x&y` value are treated as part of the value.  Change the format from `%lld` to `0x%llX` (in the original code) and from `%zu` to `0x%zX`, and the ODD lines change:

```
ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 0x800000000

ODD IT IS :), x&1 = 1, size of x&1 = 0x8
```

There are 8 zeros after the 0x8.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked ! But still, why does it give size as large as 34359738368 if I print it using %lld

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator (except when the operand is a variable length array). Given `long long x`, `sizeof(x)` is equivalent to `sizeof(long long)`, it won't change in runtime.

`long long` type is at least 64 bits, in your machine, it is 8 bytes(64bits). So nothing surprise there.